# Ошибка при добавлении навигационной панели

Tags: android

Имеется код:

```
activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/loginText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login"
        android:hint="@string/passwordText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enter"
        android:onClick="onClickButton"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package asus.example.com.oop;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickButton(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main2Activity:

package asus.example.com.oop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

nav_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/home24"
        android:title="@string/home"
        />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications24"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        />

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/person24"
        android:title="@string/account"
        />
</menu>
```

При запуске выдает следующую ошибку:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{asus.example.com.oop/asus.example.com.oop.Main2Activity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML
>   file line #9: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML
>   file line #9: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

В чем проблема и как решить?

Comment: библиотека поддержки support.design подключена?

Comment: @pavlofff, в build gradle в dependencies есть строка compile 'com.android.support:design'. Это то что надо?